# Eddy Currents and magnet's orientation with respect to motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am doing a report on an experiment on harmonic oscillators. We added magnets to the cart (they move with it) to provide magnetic dampening, placing the magnets once horizontally and once vertically (see below, along with the rest of the experiment setup). The rail is the conductive part that is supposed to create eddy currents.

The damping effect of the vertical (right) magnet was much stronger than the horizontal magnet, and I'd love to know why. I tried to figure it out from Faraday's Law but I can't figure out why changing the location of the north and south poles should change the total force exerted on the moving cart. Any help? Assume undergrad physics and math knowledge.

[image]

Comment: Are the magnets attached to the cart so they move with it or are they on a separate stand? And which parts of the setup are conductive?

Comment: Did you try and reposition the horizontal magnet higher and lower on the cart to see if that had an effect?

Comment: The magnets are attached to the cart and move with it. The rail itself is the conductive part.